# how to store many documents in same collection in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": ""
    },
    "email": "",
    "password": "",
    "profile": {
        "picture": "",
        "website": "",
        "location": "",
        "gender": "",
        "name": ""
    },
    "workdetails": [
     {
        "company_name": "",
        "job_title": "",
        "role": ""
    },
    {
        "company_name": "",
        "job_title": "",
        "role": ""
    },
}
```

How do I create a schema for workdetails and store multiple documents for workdetails in mongodb using nodejs. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare it as an array

```
workdetails: { type : Array , "default" : [] }
```

Insertion can be like

```
objectn.workdetails= [{
        "company_name": "",
        "job_title": "",
        "role": ""
    }, {
        "company_name": "",
        "job_title": "",
        "role": ""
    }];
yourschema.create(objectn, function (err, a, b) {
  if (err) // ...
});
```